# List within HashMap remove one value

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a list Within hashmap,

```
HashMap<String, List<String>>)
```

So one key has more than one value, how to remove only one value for a specific key..

Normally we remove value directly..

```
hashmap.remove(key);
```

which removes the value.. But i need to remove a value from the list of values..

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one","two","three");
HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>> ();

hm.add("1",list);
```

i am not sure how to remove the value "two" alone from the list for the key "1"..

Comment: You need to get the list and call `remove` on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You obtain the value via `get` and remove the relevant element from the `List` with `remove`:

```
hm.get("1").remove("two");
```

of course you have to defend yourself against the situation where get returns `null`:

```
hm.computeIfPresent("1",(k,v)->{v.remove("two");return v;});
```

which is similar to:

```
if (hm.get("1") != null) {
    hm.get("1").remove("two");
}
```

Also note that the `List` you put in your `Map` (returned by `Arrays.asList()`) has a fixed size, which means you can't remove elements from it. Calling `remove` on it will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. You can fix it by using `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one","two","three"));` instead.

Comment: @mannedear `computeIfPresent`  requires a `BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V>`, which is a function that takes two parameters (key and value in this case) and returns a value. `return v;` returns the value.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the inner List first before removing an element from it.

Something like this should do:

```
hm.get("1").remove("two");
```

Comment: what do you mean by the word `key` here?, is it that you are referring to the `key` of `HashMap<key, value>` ?

Comment: He used it in his example. For better understanding I kept it like this. It is the entry of the list that should get removed.

Comment: So you edited your answer now by replacing the word `key` with `"two"`, this makes sense now.

Comment: If you look at his examples you clearly see that key couldn't have been the key of hashmap since the key is "1". And my first get has also "1"
`hm.add("1",list);`